# How to retrieve SVN Repository URL (only) for a file

Tags: svn, version-control

I want to retrieve the SVN repository URL only from the file which is checked out locally. I know there is a SVN Info command, but it gives too much info along with URL. I only need the URL which I am planning to save to Clipboard on menu click. Is it possible without going into parsing the result of SVN Info command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I don't think so](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html). But it's quite simple to filter out. E.g., on Windows:

```
D:\example>svn info foo.php | findstr URL:
URL: https://www.example.com:8443/svn/foo.php
```

On Unix (untested):

```
svn info foo.php | grep URL:
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option on Windows using PowerShell:

```
[xml]$svninfo = svn info FILENAME --xml;
$svninfo.info.entry.url;
```

Or without XML:

```
(svn info FILENAME |select-string "\burl")[0].Line.replace("URL: ","")
```

The [PSCX](https://pscx.codeplex.com/) extensions have an `Out-Clipboard` cmdlet which will let you dump the string to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a few years late to this question, so it is possible that the APIs have changed to allow my answer.

Windows command prompt:

```
svn info FILENAME --show-item url
```